# error in this code is "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files" provide solution other than changing the file extension

Tags: javascript

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import fs from 'fs';
import pickle from 'pickle';

export default function predict(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const { salt, vinegar } = req.body;

    // Load the model from the pickle file
    const model = fs.readFileSync('./pickle_model.pkl');
    const pickleModel = pickle.load(model);

    // Make a prediction using the model
    const prediction = pickleModel.predict([[salt, vinegar]]);

    res.status(200).json({ quality: prediction[0][0] }); 
}
```

help me! I am trying to make next js website with tailwind css, for my pickle model

Comment: the only solution other than making this a `.ts` file is to remove the type annotations, as those are not valid in plain Javascript

Comment: *"other than changing the file extension"* - If you want to use TypeScript, why exactly do you not want to put that TypeScript code in `.ts` files?  You seem to have a strange mix of requirements here.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a javascript file, there are no types, that's what Typescript is for. In your `predict` method you have two arguments req and res that you are trying to set to Type NextApiRequest and NextApiResponse respectively. That is Typescript syntax and needs to be in a `.ts.` file and *transpiled* into javascript code your browser can read.